# props undefined (component update)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I got simple blog (react/redux) (only frontend part). With user registration and articles. And stuck when tryed to send props to component. This is might be a dumb question, readed the same questions here - how to pass props to component, tryed do this, but my props always undefined. I duess I missed something important, and can't understand what. may be something with Promises. Tryed do it 5 days - with no result. May be it just some silli mistake, and i'm just can't catch it. Plz help if you have good knowledge in React.

Main problem - "ArticlesList" component props is alwais undefined. I got the articles list in server responce. But at the page its still "Loading".

one more question - should I use react hooks instead of classes? will it be easier to write code using hooks?

here is the code:
https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-currying-f27yh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add articlesList reducer:

```
export default (history) => combineReducers({
    articlesList, // you are missing this
    authorization,
    mainstate,
    router: connectRouter(history)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I briefly looked through your code, and the problem is that you aren't actually passing your props when rendering the `MainView` component. So when you try to pass those props on to the `ArticlesList` component, they will remain undefined.

What you will need to do is pass those `props` when you render `MainView` like this:

```
<MainView 
  tab={tab} 
  loading={loading}
  articles={articles}
  pager={pager}
  articlesCount={articlesCount}
  currentPage={currentPage}
/>
```

Where you define the values for those props above, I have no idea. I can't look through all of your code, but it is a good starting point.

Comment: ty. but it should work without it, just forget to add reducer in combineReducers(). thx to @lissettdm for help

Comment: ah ok guess I need to look at redux some more